# Calculating sum using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table whose column name is **"price"**. How do I calculate the sum of all prices of all products and store it in a variable in **jquery**

```
<table id ="tab">
    <th>Product</th><th>Price</th>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>752</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>652</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>1000</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do it where you generate those values in js file. try not to use your data from dom.

Comment: Do not use data from your dom unless you are scrapping. This is really a bad practice.

Comment: How Sir, could u please elaborate ... I really didn't get the idea... @ Krishnadas Sir

Comment: If you have this data in your database use some functions/apis to calculate this. Now what you are doing is like stealing your own data. You can access it from your databse that is the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('#tab tr td:nth-of-type(2)').each(function(i, cell) {
    sum += parseInt($(cell).text(),10);
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>752</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>652</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: should provide radix of parseInt()

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
<script>
    var sum=0;
    $('#tab').find('tr').each(function(i,v){
       sum=sum+parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    })
    alert(sum);
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `:second` selector

Answer (score 3):

Using `map()` and `reduce()` to create a one liner

```js
var sum = $('tr td:nth-child(2)')
  .map((_, el) => +$(el).text().trim() || 0).get()
  .reduce((a, c) => a + c);
  
console.log('Sum =',sum)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>752</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>652</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var total = 0;
   $('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
  total+=parseInt($(this).text());
   })
   alert(total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table id ="tab">
    <th>Product</th><th>Price</th>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>752</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>652</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>1000</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your price is in the last element of your each `tr`. then you can try this

```
var total  = 0;

$('#tab tr td:last-child').each(function(index) {
  total = total + parseInt($(this).text());
});

alert(total);
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/uwhLjwce/

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following method

```
function getTotalPrice() {
    var output = 0;
    var priceCells = $("#tab tr td:nth-child(2)");
    var text;
    var value

    for (var i = 0, len = priceCells.length; i < len; i++) {
        text = $(priceCells[i]).text();
        value = parseInt(text, 10);
        output += value;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: `nth-child` is not zero based